# Is there a way to change a div's children's styles and then move the children outside of the div while keeping their new style from the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to append a group of elements to a div and then change the css style of the div (and therefore also changing the style of the children) and then take the group of elements back out with the new css style it got from the parent div?

First I append all the child elements into the div with:

```
var target_children = document.getElementsByClassName(ndmove);
    for (let i = 0; i < target_children.length; i++) {
        plane.appendChild(target_children[i]);
    }
```

('plane' is the id of the div I'm appending the children to).

Then I rotate the plane with:

```
plane.style.transform = "rotateX(90deg)";
```

(My program should be able to rotate in all three dimensions).

Finally, I append the children back to the original div ("cube") with:

```
let cube = document.getElementById("cube");
        while (plane.firstChild) {
            let target_block = plane.lastChild;
            cube.appendChild(target_block);
        }
```

The "cube" div is contains all of the children (the "target_children" are only the specific children that I would like to append for that invocation of a function based on its input) and the "plane" div.
Basically:

```
<div id="cube" class="cube">
    <div id="plane" class="plane"></div>
    <div child></div>
    <div child></div>
    ...
</div>
```

If there is a better way to rotate the "target_children", I'm fine to completely restart this project.

Comment: What I don't understand: why the back and forth? Any specific reason for moving here and there your elements?  Your question as it currently stands is too broad and hard to understand. What's the reasoning behind? What are you building? Please create a [mcve] - [edit] and explain better what you're **actually** after.

Comment: I guess you could add a class to those children whenever they become a child of the div, which would stay even if you moved them out.

Comment: The trick will be inherited styles, you'll need to capture them and transfer them to the temporary child.

Comment: @pilchard - could you please elaborate, I can't find what you mean by "inherited styles".

Comment: @pso - if there is a class that, for example, is rotateX(90deg), once I add that class to an element that might already be rotated around the x axis by a variable amount of degrees, will the new rotation be 90 degrees more or just 90 degrees?

Comment: @Bobobby same styles dont stack, the more specific one will be active

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm creating a rubik's cube which has all of it's tiny squares (54 in total, 9 for each 3x3 side) inside a "cube" div. I want to be able to twist any of the sides by moving them inside another div and rotating that div with all of the pieces I want to rotate. I am currently trying to create a smaller version of my current project.

Comment: @pso would you happen to know how to make it so that I can rotate something from it's current rotation? I tried researching for it but all I can find is a deleted post.
edit: nevermind, I thought of a solution to avoid having to know the current rotation.